# Resizing UINavigationBar frame leaves a black unresponsive view area in view controller's view

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to adjust the height of a UINavigationBar to make it smaller but my view shows a black view where the navigation bar used to be. I tried changing my view's frame to cover this black area but it doesn't seem to be working.

**Code:**

```
- (IBAction)reduceNavigationBarHeight:(id)sender {

    CGRect frameToChange = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
    frameToChange.size.height -= 5;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = frameToChange;

    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y -= 5;
    viewFrame.size.height += 5;
    self.view.frame = viewFrame;

}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the status bar, you can hide the same as

```
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)])
    {
        // iOS 7
        [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
    } else 
    {
        // iOS 6
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
    }

    - (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
        return YES;
    }
```

Comment: I dont have any issues with the status bar. It's the black view where the navigation bar used to be is the problem here. I can't seem to adjust my view to cover the black area.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
  CGRect frameToChange = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
  frameToChange.size.height -= 5;
  self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = frameToChange;

}
```

**Or**

if you are using Autolayout then  -

```
CGRect frameToChange = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:navigationBar attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1 constant:frameToChange.size.height - 5.0]];
```